# When i try to find even numbers with where() method in 1-D array, it returns me odd numbers. Why?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working on numpy and when i was trying numpy methods on my editor, i noticed an anormal situation for me.

Firstly, I created a numpy array (nd.array) like that:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

After that, I tried to get even numbers from the array and I wrote this code line:

```
even_numbers_in_array = np.where(arr%2 == 0)
```

and I thought it should return a tuple that contains even numbers but it returns me opposite of that:

```
In [33]: even_numbers_in_array
Out[33]: (array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11], dtype=int64),)
```

after this result, I was shocked because there are `9`, `10`, `11` values even if they are not in the array.
Can anybody explain that strange situation to me?

Thank you

I use spyder(anaconda3) editor and w11 operating system

Comment: Actually you should be shocked that you didn't get a NameError for `arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `np.where`:

```
>>> arr[arr % 2 == 0]
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

**Note: `np.where` returns the index not the number itself.**

```
>>> arr[np.where(arr % 2 == 0)[0]]
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```

You are confused because you use a particular array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. Try with another series:

```
arr = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])

>>> np.where(arr % 2 == 0)
(array([1, 3, 5, 7]),)

>>> arr[arr % 2 == 0]
array([12, 14, 16, 18])
```